# Symfony 3.4 use yml file in getConfigTreeBuilder

Tags: symfony

Using Symfony 3.4, I have a new bundle with it own configuration. Everything works, but I would like to know if I can use a bundle yml file into my Configuration Tree building ?

I have in my file `src/MyNewBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php` :

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');

    // set default value here for configuration if no configuration provided in app/config/config.yml
    $rootNode
        ->children()
        ->scalarNode('url_api1')->defaultValue('https://url.api1.com')->end()
        ->scalarNode('url_api2')->defaultValue('https://url.api2.com')->end()
        ->end()
    ;

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

Is it common to define default values here ? This is not really convenient, is there a way to load for example the parameters.yml file of the bundle ? I tried, but the `Loader` expects a `ContainerBuilder`, I can't access it in `Configuration.php`.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking.  You can have a MyBundle/Resources/my_bundle_config.yml file and load it inside of MyBundleExtension.  Values from the app config file will basically be merged with the bundle's config file.  But I think you are asking for something else.

Comment: I understand this file `Configuration.php` allows to define some default values, this way you don't have to merge bundle config to your main config app file. I was wondering if you can define default values using .yml file. Using this system, config are not merge in my app, you can override them into /app/config/config.yml but defaults are here.

Comment: I was pretty sure I was not understanding what you are asking.  Still don't.

Comment: I am defining default values for my Bundle. I am asking how to grab the config from .yml file, instead of using pure php. According to the doc : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/configuration.html, I understand you can provide default values in this file, but how to grab defaults from `/MyBundle/Ressoures/config/parameters.yml` ? Or I didnt' understand how to define default config for my Bundle.

Comment: You are not just defining default values, but also the schema of your config file: the possible parameters it can take which are optional or can repeat, etc.